# Multipe flush with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to load a users/students list from a .csv file.
Each student is a member of one promotion.

In the file I have the users' infos and the name of his promotion.
So i have to insert all promotions before inserting students. This part works.

```php
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    /* WORKS FROM THIS */
    $start = new \DateTime();
    $output->writeln('[START] time : ' . $start->format('H:i:s'));
    $f = fopen($input->getArgument('filename'), 'r');

    if ($input->getOption('has-headers'))
        fgetcsv($f, null, ',');

    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $um = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $promoRepo = $em->getRepository('PlanningBundle:Promotion');
    $promotions = $promoRepo->findAll();
    /** @var Promotion[] $promosIDX */
    $promosIDX = array();

    foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
        $promosIDX[$promotion->getName()] = $promotion;
    }

    while ($user = fgetcsv($f)) {

        if (!array_key_exists($user[7], $promosIDX)) {
            $promotion = new Promotion();
            $promotion->setName($user[7])
                ->setDateEnd(new \DateTime())
                ->setDateStart(new \DateTime());

            $em->persist($promotion);
        }
    }

    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();

    $doctrine->resetManager();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    /* TO THIS */
    $f = fopen($input->getArgument('filename'), 'r');

    if ($input->getOption('has-headers'))
        fgetcsv($f, null, ',');

    $promoRepo = $em->getRepository('PlanningBundle:Promotion');

    $userRepo = $em->getRepository('PlanningBundle:User');

    $i = 0;
    while ($user = fgetcsv($f)) {

        $student = new Student();
        $student
            ->setUsername($user[0])
            ->setEmail($user[1])
            ->setLastname($user[2])
            ->setFirstname($user[3])
            ->setPromotion( $promoRepo->findOneByName($user[7]) )
            ->setPassword('insta' . (new \DateTime())->format('Y'))
        ;

        if( is_null($userRepo->findOneByUsername($student->getUsername())) ) {
            $i++;
            $um->updateUser($student, false);
        }

        if (($i % 20) == 0) {
            try {
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $output->writeln('[ERROR] reason : ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    try {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output->writeln('[ERROR] reason : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $end = new \DateTime();
    $diff = $end->diff($start);
    $output->writeln( "[END] duration : " . $diff->h . ":" .$diff->i .":" .$diff->s );

}
```

Is that correct ? I tried many possibilities, and having multiple Exceptions ...
And this one did not insert any user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used :

```
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

In order to properly reload the manager. It solves the problem and allows to avoid *the entity manager is closed* exception.

Answer (score 0):

From the FOSUserBundle docs, you must create a new user using [`$um->createUser()`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md#creating-a-new-user) instead of `new Student()`:

```
$student = $um->createUser();
```

[This is also noted in the `updateUser()` method.](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md#updating-a-user-object)

Comment: The point is that I've created the User class, as FOS mentioned it but I've also created the sub-classes Student, Tutor and Teacher and used doctrine inheritance mapping, so, tell me if I'm wrong, but if I want this to be in `createUser()` method I need to extends FOS user manager ?